# How to include large school projects in CV for Freshers

Tags: resume, software-industry, fresher

I am a fresh graduate of Software Engineering and I need help on creating a good CV for freshers. As I have no work experience, I want to include some of our large academic software projects which I contributed in. I need help on what are some good formats of listing them. Should it include project name(of course), my role, duration, and technologies/skills used in the project,etc? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [As a student, how should programming language familiarity be described on a CV/Resume](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/as-a-student-how-should-programming-language-familiarity-be-described-on-a-cv-r)

Comment: Sorry, but I am asking of school projects like:
Projects Detail
1 - Library Information System [National Library, NY,USA ]
Duration: Mar 2005 - Jun 2005
Team Size: 3
Role Played: Developer and Tester
Skills Used: Pro*C, Red Hat Linux, MySQL

Comment: I don't agree this is a duplicate to the question linked, because this question is about representing student project work in lieu of work experience, and not just about listing skills learned during those projects.

Comment: Other than indicating it is a school project, how is it formatted any different than a work project you list on your CV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm speaking here as both a hiring manager and as someone who has taught university courses in employment portfolio creation for new graduates.  **Yes**, including university projects in lieu of professional work experience is a very good thing to do, as is being as complete as possible without being *too* verbose.

You have several options for displaying that information -- just remember the ultimate goal should be to make it as clear to understand as possible for the reviewer.  The person reviewing your resume for entry-level or junior positions should already be oriented toward reading about student or non-traditional work experience, so none of the following options (or one you make up on your own) should come as any great shock to them.

Instead of a "Work Experience" section of your CV, you can just use a "Student Project Experience" section, or something similarly titled.  The information you list in your question is very good information to include.  You can format it something like this:

> Team Member, Project X (Advanced Widgetmaking course, Spring 2013)
>
> - Brief description of project
> - Brief description of your specific work on the project
> - Technologies used: list goes here

Or, you could combine all the technologies/skills used under a single "Skills" heading, and list as you would on a traditional resume.

Similarly, you could instead highlight the advanced/elective/special/interesting coursework you took (all the good stuff beyond intro courses), and list the projects under each course listing.

Personally, I've always preferred the first option I gave, because it looks most like what your traditional work experience will look like once you have it.  And, once you have that professional experience, the project experience should start to be deemphasized on your resume -- but don't feel like you need to do that immediately, especially if your course projects were comprehensive and applicable to your career.

Answer (score 0):

I usually put everything up on GitHub and have a link to my profile on my Resume.

Also, you could use LinkedIn to do the same, where you explain the projects you worked on and they role that you had in the group!

Hope that helps!